# How to query only rows that reached record count

Tags: sql

I have an unique query requirement and I can't use stored procedures or UDF.

I need to run a query that will return date and record count for a given predicate (example: device_id) and stop as soon as it reaches cumulative record count/day to 1000)

See the example below (look at the second table, that is the expected result)

Sample data:

| Device-ID | date | rec-count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 01/01/2022 | 500 |
| 124 | 01/01/2022 | 500 |
| 123 | 01/02/2022 | 250 |
| 124 | 01/02/2022 | 350 |
| 124 | 01/03/2022 | 500 |
| 123 | 01/04/2022 | 280 |
| 124 | 01/04/2022 | 500 |
| 123 | 01/05/2022 | 300 |

Expected output is:

| Device-ID | date | rec-count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 01/01/2022 | 500 |
| 123 | 01/02/2022 | 250 |
| 123 | 01/04/2022 | 280 |
| 124 | 01/02/2022 | 350 |
| 124 | 01/01/2022 | 500 |
| 124 | 01/03/2022 | 500 |

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language used by all relational databases, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a cumulative sum using a window function:

```
select device_id, date, rec_count
from (
  select device_id, date, 
         sum(rec_count) over (partition by device_id order by date) as rec_count
  from the_table
  where device_id = 123
) t
where rec_count <= 1000;
```

Given the `where  clause of the inner query, the` partition by device_id` isn't really needed, but that way the query can easily be extended to work for multiple IDs.

The above is pure standard ANSI SQL and should work on any modern DBMS.

Comment: my original query is:SELECT 
 device_name, date(time) as trx_date, count(*) record_count 
  FROM table_name
  group by device_name,date(time)
  order by device_name, trx_date

whre my time field contains date and time at nanosecond interval (all I need is date and I can use date(time) to get the date (mm/dd/yyyy)

Comment: Almost ANSI SQL compliant, `date` is an ANSI/ISO SQL reserved word and needs to be delimited. (Still upvoted though.)